# Vertical sliders in Flutter aligned side by side

Tags: dart, flutter

I have these sliders which by default are obviously aligned underneath each other:

```
class _Grid extends State<Grid> {

  var val = 5;

  @override
  build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Game"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 1.0,
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            new Slider(
              value: val.toDouble(),
              min: 1.0,
              max: 50.0,
              divisions: 50,
              label: '$val',
              onChanged: (double newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  val = newValue.round();
                });
              },
            ),
            new Slider(
              value: val.toDouble(),
              min: 1.0,
              max: 50.0,
              divisions: 50,
              label: '$val',
              onChanged: (double newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  val = newValue.round();
                });
              },
            ),    
          ],
         )
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

But instead of the user dragging the value from left to right, I want the value to be dragged from bottom to top (basically rotated). And they should align side by side.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The slider component does not support switching the axis from horizontal to vertical. Google's [Material Design guidelines on sliders](https://material.io/guidelines/components/sliders.html) do not show any examples of vertical sliders, so maybe it's something which is not recommended.

While you could technically rotate the sliders using a RotatedBox or the Transform class, that messes up the position calculation for the sliders. The slider class uses a `HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer`, so the thumb position change will be adjusted based on horizontal instead of vertical drags.

The following code example shows the problem. Sliders are rotated, but only finger movements on the horizontal axis will update the scrollthumb position:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Vertical sliders',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new SliderGrid(),
    );
  }
}

class SliderGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GridState createState() => new _GridState();
}

class _GridState extends State<SliderGrid> {
  var val = 5;

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Game"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        elevation: 1.0,
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Transform(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          // Rotate sliders by 90 degrees
          transform: new Matrix4.identity()..rotateZ(90 * 3.1415927 / 180),
            child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              new Slider(
                value: val.toDouble(),
                min: 1.0,
                max: 50.0,
                divisions: 50,
                label: '$val',
                onChanged: (double newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    val = newValue.round();
                  });
                },
              ),
              new Slider(
                value: val.toDouble(),
                min: 1.0,
                max: 50.0,
                divisions: 50,
                label: '$val',
                onChanged: (double newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    val = newValue.round();
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That leaves you with the option to create a vertical slider implementation based on the current slider code base. Copy-paste the content of [slider.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/slider.dart) into a new file in your project and import it. In that file, replace all instances of `HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer` with `VerticalDragGestureRecognizer`. In combination with the rotation code above, it should now handle gestures properly.

I haven't found any [open Flutter issues filed to create a vertical slider](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20%20slider%20), looks like there is no plan to create one right now.

Update: Created [Flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10500) to add support for vertical sliders.

Comment: Great answer! I edited it to be more specific about the edits to slider.dart that are necessary to enable vertical dragging.

Comment: Feel free to open an issue about not being able to rotate a slider.

Comment: Great, just did that! See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10500

Comment: Just an update on this answer: I've just tried wrapping a standard Slider in a RotatedBox, and it works fine with no adjustments. Perhaps the code has been updated since this answer was posted to better handle gesture detection and rotated elements.

Answer (score 33):

Updated answer for 2019: wrapping a Slider inside a RotatedBox works

**Edit**: ... if you are not using a label. The RotatedBox also rotates the value indicator so the label text will paint as vertical. Unfortunate that label isn't a widget which we can also rotate, but looking at the source code looks like this would be difficult to change.

```
RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: 1,
  child: Slider(
     value: ...,
     onChanged: (newValue) {
       ...
     },
  ),
)
```

Comment: Not quite working like a charm, since the text in the `label` bubble is also rotated. I suppose it will have to do for now, though.

Comment: Maybe we can figure out a way to just disable the label bubble

Comment: @Abion47 Maybe you can customize the painting of Slider/RangeSlider (since it is highly customizable), and paint a rotated text. then the text will be rotated back

Comment: @ch271828n If you're going to go through the trouble of customizing the painting of the widget, just change the track to be rendered vertically and eliminate the need for this hack.

Comment: This creates slider inverted vertically (bottom of the slider is on top). It should be `quarterTurns: 3,`. Or at least it works that way for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve **vertical slider** by this [[flutter_xlider 3.4.0]](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider)

**Sample Code:**

```
FlutterSlider(
  axis: Axis.vertical,
  values: [300],
  max: 500,
  min: 0,
  onDragging: (handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue) {
    _lowerValue = lowerValue;
    _upperValue = upperValue;
    setState(() {});
  },
);
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Hope this helps you or someone else