# How to make instagram like Slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, instagram

How can I make Instagram like a slider in flutter like in the image?[image]

Comment: Here is a solution for this vertical slider remaining you can design slider by your own choice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341650/vertical-sliders-in-flutter-aligned-side-by-side

Comment: @ArslanKaleem I made the vertical slider but the main thing is I cannot draw a look-alike slider shape.

Comment: okay I'll try if I achieve the task I'll post as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, This is a workaround. I did it by adding an image to the container. Then disappear the slider and give the slider height + 20 to the container. and the Instagram slider has completed. If anyone has a solution other than this let me know.